# Whats the sum of the remaining solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

One solution of the equation $x^3-15x^2+51x-5=0$ is $5$.  Find the sum of the remaining solutions.

Comment: That is not a differential equation.

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)  and [tagging it correctly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9961/42969) are  important parts of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: So what's the sum of **all** the solutions of the cubic?

Comment: @Katerinakoufou You asked that already! Simply take the sum of **all** solutions and subtract $5$.

Comment: It would help if you said what level you are at. The comments are assuming you are past A-Level (if in the UK), but if you are before A-Level see MPW's "Answer giving hint" below.

Answer (score 2):

Viete's theorem states that the sum all roots is the coefficient of $x^2$ term with a negative sign. Say $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are roots of the equation, then
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=15$$
If one of the roots is $5$ then the sum of other two is $15-5=10$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $x=5$ is a solution, then $(x-5)$ is a factor of the LHS. Perform polynomial division to obtain a factorization of the LHS which will have $(x-5)$ and some quadratic as factors. Proceed from there.